# Underscore _.each array in template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a JSON with multiple objects as follows:

```
  {
  "taskId": 100,
  "name": "I-9 Form",
  "desc": "Form I-9",
  "dueDate": "0",
  "links": [{"link1": "http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf"},   {"link2": "http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf"}],
  "status": "Completed",
  "comments": ""
}
```

I want to display each link in the array in a template. I think im close with:

```
{{ _.each(model.links, function(link) { }}
    <div>Links: {{= link}}</div>
{{ }); }}
```

but this prints out

Links: [object Object]
Links: [object Object]

in the dom. What do I need to do so it prints out each link?

Comment: You data structure is wrong. If it is an array you should use same key. link instead of link1 and link2. If you would like to use it as link1 and link2, the it should not be an array. Just a plain object. Then above code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data structure is wrong. If it is an array you should use same key. link instead of link1 and link2. If you would like to use it as link1 and link2, the it should not be an array. Just a plain object. Then above code will work.

data structure:

```
{
      "taskId": 100,
      "name": "I-9 Form",
      "desc": "Form I-9",
      "dueDate": "0",
      "links": [{"link": "http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf"},   {"link": "http://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/files/form/i-9.pdf"}],
      "status": "Completed",
      "comments": ""
    }
```

template:

```
{{ _.each(model.links, function(link) { }}
    <div>Links: {{= link.link}}</div>
{{ }); }}
```

Comment: But that's the data he has, how is he supposed to correct it?

Comment: I agree, My data was incorrect. This solution works. Thanks Mu for a solution working with the data I presented!

Comment: @muistooshort : Your solution is sweet. But regarding me ask him to change the data structure is coz, "prevention is better than cure".

Answer (score 2):

If the objects in `links` always have just one key/value then you can do something like this:

```
{{= _(link).values()[0] }}
```

to work around not knowing what the keys will be.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/66vY4/